# Is it secure to use the hash of key as the IV in AES encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I need to store some sensitive data for a program. For each copy of the program, there will be a unique key for encrypting one (and only one) file using AES encryption (OFB). The key will not be changed (probably forever).

Is it secure if the hash value of the key is used as the IV?

Update:
The key is computer generated.
The user of the program have no access to the key since it's obtained by the program via secure Web API.
The user can only edit a portion of data stored in the file via the program.

Comment: Welcome to crypto; your question was migrated here by the SO mods as it is a better fit here. Feel free to register here to receive notification of your responses :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not secure.

From NIST 800-38:

```
The OFB mode requires a unique IV for every message that is ever encrypted
under the given key. If, contrary to this requirement, the same IV is used
for the encryption of more than one message, then the confidentiality of
those messages may be compromised
```

Given your description, you are *apparently* safe, because at any one time you have one file only.

However:

- A malicious user may store away an earlier version of the file and do a comparison after a change and learn which bits flipped in the first block where that happened.
- In the future, you may add a second file and not remember the rule above.

A unique (not necessarily truly random) IV per message is still recommended.

Comment: A solution to this is to store a random IV in the file header, xor'ed with the hash of the password. When you decrypt, compute the password hash and xor against the stored value, then use the result as the IV. This gives you a safe way to store the IV, and a unique IV per file.

Comment: @Polynomial Why xor the IV with the password hash? Sounds dubious to me.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It's not intended to be some hair-brained "increase the entropies!" scheme, if that's what you're concerned about. The idea is to xor the IV with the hash when storing it in the file, so it can't be known by an attacker without knowing the password.

Comment: @Polynomial: For OFB (and in general), the initialization vector doesn't have to be secret (as it will be passed through the cipher before being used).

Comment: What about other modes like CBC, ECB and CFB? Do they share the same problem?

Comment: @Lacek Reusing an IV in CBC and CFB is not as bad, but it is still insecure. ECB should simply not be used. An example of mode which is in most cases still secure enough even if the IV is wrong or abused, is [SIV](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5297).

Comment: @Polynomial and why do you want to prevent an attacker from knowing the IV?

Comment: @CodeInChaos Paranoia! :)